# sum of exponentials with particular coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

Suppose that
\begin{equation}
S=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} (-1)^k \exp(-c_k)
\end{equation}
where $c_k$ are known and positive.

Given that
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} (-1)^k c_k=0
\end{equation}
is there a way of simplifying the expression of $S$?

Thank you

Comment: Where did you see this question?

Comment: It is the last step of a calculation I made for simplifying (from an algorithmic point of view) the calculation of the determinant of a of "exponential" matrices.  An "exponential" matrix is a matrix $\bf{A}$ of dimensions $M$x$M$ whose $i,j$ entry is of the type  $\bf{A}|_{i,j}=\exp(-(a_i-a_j)^2)$, with $a_i,a_j$ real and known

Comment: If you find a way, please do post it here, I'm interested.

Comment: If I'll find a way i will post it for sure